# Office365 Reporting REST API - "The query is invalid."

Tags: rest, office365

How come I'm able to query Office365's Reporting API using the following request:

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$select=Subject,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Status,Received,Received&$filter=SenderAddress eq 'foo@bar.com' and RecipientAddress eq 'bar@foo.com' and StartDate eq datetime'2016-10-01T00:00:00' and EndDate eq datetime'2016-10-03T00:00:00'
```

but when I modify it to filter on the **subject** as well, it returns an error:

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$select=Subject,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Status,Received,Received&$filter=SenderAddress eq 'foo@bar.com' and RecipientAddress eq 'bar@foo.com' and StartDate eq datetime'2016-10-01T00:00:00' and EndDate eq datetime'2016-10-03T00:00:00' and Subject eq 'Test'
```

> {   "odata.error": {
>       "code": "InvalidQueryException",
>       "message": {
>         "lang": "",
>         "value": "The query is invalid."
>       }   } }

Comment: Do you mind posting the schema and a sample row?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when all of a sudden my query was rejected. In my case the unlikely solution was to add a decimal portion to the time value: 2018-09-13T12:27:46.0000000

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
startswith(Subject,'Test')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. We ended up doing some (unfortunately inefficient) post-processing to filter on our end.